# Binding to external libraries in Godot

Tags: c++, c, godot

I found a description here of how to add a external library to the godotengine engine: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/core_and_modules/binding_to_external_libraries.html

But I can't understand these parts:

-"You'll need to install the external library on your machine to get the .a library files. See the library's official documentation for specific instructions on how to do this for your operation system. We've included the installation commands for Linux below , for reference."

-"The external library will also need to be installed inside your module to make the source files accessible to the compiler, while also keeping the module code self-contained."

I do not understand why ?? Why do I need to add the Source code to the module, if I have already added a platform-specific built static file of this library?

Comment: Seems like it's about header files, you still need them for API. When sources will be linked statically (static library just pre-build *.obj files from compiled *.c/*.cpp package into some ZIP like archive)

Comment: @Victor Gubin, But then they would have said that heder files are needed. But they said they need the source code. This is some kind of conflicting instruction.

Comment: technically headers - also source code.

Comment: Victor Gubin, Only on condition that ALL implementations of functions are written in the header. However, in this case, this is not specified, which means that it cannot be said that the headers are the source code.